# Swift - Trying to change the app icon from within the app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to allow the user to change their app icon. However after following a tutorial when I try change to the alternative icon it just shows as a blank white icon. There is no error and it it seems to have changed but has just went blank. I have made the correct changes to the plist etc so not sure what I am missing. I have attached the code I'm using and an image of the plist.

```
 UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName("DarkIcon") { error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                print("App Icon changed!")
            }
        }
```

[Plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cc1tT.png)
[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFzpm.png)

[Copy Bundle Resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvfgc.png)

Comment: Did you include alternative icon in the Copy Bundle Resources in the Build Phases? (from screenshot it's not clear)

Comment: Hi I think they are yes, I added a screenshot of my Copy Bundle Resources

Comment: then things look right. Do the same icon files work when they are not dynamic? (i.e. if you set the same set as AppIcon in Assets?)

Answer (score -1):

[Follow the steps in this video](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=change%20icon%20swift), and delete your original plist entries before you start...